# Magento Customers by number of orders filter only complete status

Tags: magento

[image]

We want to show order state only complete. I have been tried filter in query "orders_sum_amount/orders_count" but failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in my Magento root directory, It is giving me all customers `id` and their `total order count`.

What you want is when you getting Order collection you need to use the filter on status.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete');//This gives all orders which are completed

$customerIds = array();

    foreach($orders as $v => $order){

        if(in_array($order['customer_id'],$customerIds)){

            }else{
            $customerIds[] = $order['customer_id']; 
        }   
    }// now in $customerIds you will have all customer ids.
$cIds = array_filter($customerIds);//This will remove empty value from $customerIds
    $result = array();
    foreach($cIds as $k => $customerId){
        $ord = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId);

        $result[$k]['customer_id'] = $customerId;
        $result[$k]['total_order'] = count($ord->getData());
    }

    echo "<pre>";print_r($result);die;
```

And in `$result` array you will have all customer ids and their total order count.

Comment: If it's working then you should accept the answer @Anwar